# Search forward / backward (`*` / `#`) in visual select mode

Tags: neovim, search, visual-mode, movement

This seems to be a mismatch in behavior between Vim and Neovim.

In Vim, when in visual selection mode, `*` and `#` work as expected:
they jump forward / backward to the next occurrence of the word under
the cursor *while preserving visual select*. As a result the selection
gets extended to the cursor position after the jump.

Neovim however *aborts visual select mode* and instead searches for
the next occurrence of the selected text. This is quite irritating as
when in visual select mode, all other movements expand the selection
and `*`/`#` are the odd ones out. (Even `g*`/`g#` work like they should
Neovim, but the functionality is of course not the same as `*`/`#`.)
This is wildly inconsistent and I strongly prefer Vim’s behavior.
`*`/`#` is one of the main ways I move around in files and I expect it
to behave the same regardless of what mode I’m in.

Is there a way to make Neovim behave like Vim here?

Comment: Possibly `:xnoremap * <cmd>*`? Let me know if this works